# mysql workbench records limit

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, mysql-workbench

I perform an SQL query on a database with MySQL and I get back only the first 1000 rows from 24000 expected. If i export the results to an XML form, I get the first 1000 again.
Is there a way to disable that limit and get back all the rows?
Otherwise, I will have to merge 24 XML files :/

Comment: Maybe this question on superuser can help you: http://superuser.com/questions/240291/how-to-remove-1000-row-limit-in-mysql-workbench-queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do these steps:

1. Go to Edit -> Preferences.
2. Click on the SQL Editor tab.
3. Under Query Editor, uncheck Limit Rows.

**Edit**

Workbench Version 6.12 (Mac OS(10.11.3))

1. Go to Edit -> Preferences.
2. Click on the SQL Editor tab.
3. Under SQL Execution, uncheck Limit Rows.

Comment: this worked fine, but it ran out of memory.. so I have to split the results anyway

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend simply clicking the "Toggle limitation of the records number" button located right above the results pane. Turning off the limit is not the best approach since the server will have to send all records with every query. Placing a limit on the rows returned is generally a good idea.